# Nested SQL Select Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number of tables across two databases that I would like to pulll information out of to display in a grid in a web page.

If I run the following sql it works fine and only returns one row:

```
Select DISTINCT s.STUDENT#, s.SURNAME,s.GIVEN_NAME,ar.EN_EMAIL,ar.CAREGIVER_NO,i.GIVENNAME,i.SURNAME,i.EMAIL,i.EMAIL_BILLING,ax.CORR_PREFERENCE
      from 
            [PCSchool].[dbo].[STUDENT] s
        INNER JOIN  [PCSchool].[dbo].[ALUMREL] ar
            on s.STUDENT# = ar.CHILD#
        LEFT JOIN
                [PCSchool].[dbo].[IDENTITY] i 
            on ar.PARENT# = i.[MEMBER#]
        left join   [PCSchool].[dbo].[ALUMREL_EX] ax
            on ar.parent# = ax.PARENT#
    where  (ar.PARENT# <> ar.FAMILY_HASH) and ax.CORR_PREFERENCE = 1 and ar.EN_EMAIL = 'I' where s.STUDENT#=7282)
```

[image: Result form above query for one user]

What my problem is, I have another table that has a list of students that has a counter in it and a detention type.

[image: List of Students and their detentions]

I want to be able to pull the above email information from one table based on the Detention table.  The StudentCode in the detention table and the Student# in the above table are the same for each student.

I have no idea whether this can be done with SQL or whether  I need to do it via server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using join of detention table

```
Select DISTINCT s.STUDENT#, s.SURNAME,s.GIVEN_NAME,ar.EN_EMAIL,ar.CAREGIVER_NO,i.GIVENNAME,i.SURNAME,i.EMAIL,i.EMAIL_BILLING,ax.CORR_PREFERENCE,detentype,detentioncount
      from 
            [PCSchool].[dbo].[STUDENT] s
        INNER JOIN  [PCSchool].[dbo].[ALUMREL] ar
            on s.STUDENT# = ar.CHILD#
        LEFT JOIN
                [PCSchool].[dbo].[IDENTITY] i 
            on ar.PARENT# = i.[MEMBER#]
        left join   [PCSchool].[dbo].[ALUMREL_EX] ax
            on ar.parent# = ax.PARENT#
        left join Detention on Detention.studentcode=s.STUDENT#
    where  (ar.PARENT# <> ar.FAMILY_HASH) and ax.CORR_PREFERENCE = 1 and ar.EN_EMAIL = 'I' where s.STUDENT#=7282)
```

Comment: Thanks @fa06 I tweaked the SQL a tiny bit and it is giving me exactly what I needed.  I did have that join in, but in the incorrect place.  Your a genius!!

Answer (score 0):

Joining the two results_set would get you want you want?

```
select a.student#,a.email 
  from (<first_query>) a
  join students b
    on a.student#=b.studentcode
```